# Return results of RecognizerListener to the class that called it

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I am using SpeechRecognizer and RecognizerListener in my SoftKeyboard app.  I can get results from the listener but triggering the results to automatically be added to the InputConnection is proving problematic... heres some code..

```
public class SoftKeyboard extends InputMethodService 
    implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {

private SpeechRecognizer getMsg = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
public static String mResult = "";


// a bunch of code that is irrelavent to my question   


public void getVoice () {
    mResult = "";
    context = this;
    if (isListening == false) {
        isListening = true;
            Intent intent = new Intent (RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);        
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getClass().getPackage().getName());        
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speech recognition demo");        
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);        
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 5); 
            Talk doMsg = new Talk();
            getMsg.setRecognitionListener(doMsg);
            getMsg.startListening(intent);
    }

     }

    public void putText () {
        getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(mResult, 1);
    }
}

class Talk implements RecognitionListener {
Context context = SoftKeyboard.context;


public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Beginning of Speech", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
    //Toast.makeText(context, "Buffer received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}

public void onEndOfSpeech() {
    Toast.makeText(context, "End Of Speech", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

public void onError(int error) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(context, "There was an Error: "+String.valueOf(error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    SoftKeyboard.isListening = false;
}

public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Event: "+String.valueOf(eventType), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}

public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Partial Results to be had", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Ready For Speech!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}

public void onResults(Bundle results) {
    ArrayList<String> result = results.getStringArrayList("results_recognition");
    if (result.isEmpty() == false) {
        for (int i = 0; i<(result.size()-1);i++) {
            Toast.makeText(context, result.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        SoftKeyboard.mResult = result.get(0);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "no results", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        SoftKeyboard.mResult = "-1";
    }
    SoftKeyboard.isListening = false;
    SoftKeyboard.putText();
}

public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
}

}
```

so I call the getVoice method from the press of a button and it works fine until I call the putText method back in the SoftKeyboard.  I can only call a static method from the onResult method but if I make putText a static method I can't call the getCurrentInputConnection... the only way I've found is for the user to click the button a second time to insert the text but this is not very user friendly.  I want to call the getCurrentInputConnection automatically after the onResult method in the Listener runs, but the static / non-static conflict is very troublesome here.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS. Does it help?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I tried it and it didn't help.  My problem is that doMsg is a static object, so when I try to execute the non-static method getCurrentInputConnection().commitText from the onResults method in the RecognitionListener doMsg it is not allowed.  I need a way to execute a non-static command with a static object.  Either that or I need to make doMsg non-static.  I tried to implement a listener for when doMsg sets the value of mResult but I could not get that to work.  So my best solution is to require the user to press a button to insert the text.